# Formulas Combining Mathematics and Algorithmic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, algorithms

I am organizing an algorithmic lecture at my university, which is more theoretical. Regarding Landau-notation and runtime analysis, using algorithms that implement mathematical formulas is great. In my opinion, it helps the students see the connection. Of course, I also want some difficult exercises, and I am searching for mathematical functions that have a very algorithimal touch, if you know what I mean. Because it is hard to describe, here are two examples of such functions: [nth prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) and [nth Dedekind number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number).

Can you provide me with similar formulas?

Comment: What does the nth prime have to do with wilson's theorem? And this question is more appropriate on matheducators.se

Comment: I meant Wilson's formula. Different Wilson :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple formula for the divisor function, which counts the number of divisors of an integer.

$$d(x)=-1+\lceil\sqrt x\rceil-\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor+2\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}[1-\lceil\frac x n\rceil+\lfloor\frac x n\rfloor]$$

This formula is equivalent to the trial division algorithm, which is the simplest to implement, although it is not used in practice because its time complexity is exponential with respect to the number of digits of the number to be factored.

Comment: This is great! Practical application is optional!

Comment: Doesn't this also require exponential complexity in the number of digits $m$, where $m\approx \log x$?

Comment: The time complexity of this formula is $O(b^{\frac k 2})$, where $b$ is the base and $k$ is the number of digits.